# e.preventDefault() on a link still loads the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

the title may be a bit misleading but I'm not sure how to phrase it better, so I apologize for that.

I'm creating a custom handler so the site doesn't refresh when new content is pressed (similar to how youtube works, for example).

For that I'm using this script:

```
$('.sidebar2 li a').click(function (e) {
    test = true;
    var button = $(this);
    var noteId = button.data("noteid");

    $(".sidebar2 li.active").removeClass("active");
    var postData = { id: noteId };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/API/Note',
        type: 'get',
        data: postData,
        success: function (resp) {
            if (resp.success == true) {
                $('#app-bar-left').html(resp.note.navBarHTML);
                $('#cell-content').html(resp.note.noteContentHTML);
                window.history.pushState({ path: window.location.href }, resp.note.title, '/MyNotes/Note/' + resp.note.noteId);
                document.title = resp.note.title;
                $('*[data-noteId="'+resp.note.noteId+'"]').parent().addClass("active")

                e.preventDefault();
                test = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
});
```

even though I've stated `e.preventDefault()` to trigger, javascript loads the new content into the current frame without refreshing, but the browser refreshes again anyway.

I've tried to use `href="#"` however in this case when I go back and handle that, I always end up with two same pages, one without and one with # at the end, and in addition to that it wouldn't be very user friendly to have all links `href="#"`

What am I doing wrong to make the browser redirect "normally" even though I've told him no no no?

I've also tried adding `onclick="javascript:void(0)"` on `a` elements and that didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ajax` is async. By the time success callback is called event will already be bubbled up the DOM tree and processed. You need to call `preventDefault` before sending a request.

```
$('.sidebar2 li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // here for example
    test = true;
    var button = $(this);
    var noteId = button.data("noteid");

    $(".sidebar2 li.active").removeClass("active");
    var postData = { id: noteId };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/API/Note',
        type: 'get',
        data: postData,
        success: function (resp) {
            if (resp.success == true) {
                $('#app-bar-left').html(resp.note.navBarHTML);
                $('#cell-content').html(resp.note.noteContentHTML);
                window.history.pushState({ path: window.location.href }, resp.note.title, '/MyNotes/Note/' + resp.note.noteId);
                document.title = resp.note.title;
                $('*[data-noteId="'+resp.note.noteId+'"]').parent().addClass("active")


                test = false;
                // returning here makes no sense also
                // return false; 
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Similar with `return` inside `success`. First it has nowhere to return to and even if it did would return far too late

Comment: Thank you Yuri, that's exactly what I was looking for. My idea was to add preventDefault inside the success so it can fall-back to normal loading in case ajax fails or something, didn't think it'd cause additional problems. Any idea how I could go around that maybe? (by that I mean that the website loads "default-ly" in case ajax fails)

Comment: @DethoRhyne You could add `error` callback and manually change `window.location.href` or `window.location.hash` depending on your requirements.